# Restore after Terminate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Engine Yard AppCloud service. I just terminated my instance. How I can restore /data folder and databases?

Answer (score 0):

Engine Yard AppCloud by default will snapshot the /data volumes on the app_master and the /db volume on the db_master.  All utility instances snapshot /data as well.

Upon termination of the environment snapshots are created, and if you boot the environment back up it should automatically select the last snapshots available however you can select Custom option when Booting to select a particular snapshot if you'd like.

For more information visit our [documentation](http://docs.engineyard.com/appcloud/guides/environments/using-snapshots) site.